# IIS 7.0 404-File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am running my web application on IIS 7.0.And i left my app untouched for 30 minutes and then click the submit button.i got this error.

**The resource you are looking for might have been removed,had it's name changed,or is temporarily unavailable**

I thought it is because of session timeout and I gave session timeout to 300 minutes but it was not fine.I have been searching for solution on google and still cant find it.

Any help is appreciated
Thank You All

Comment: @MairajAhmad Problem is on IIS sir.everything is ok if u run with localserver from visual studio

Comment: I know but i just wanted to check that if there is something in the code.

Comment: Is this issue fixed ? Can you give the resolution ?